# How to run multiple batch files in subfolders (without for loop) in batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a Main folder which contains 3 subfolders. I want to make a batch file in my main folder that will execute the batch files in 3 subfolders at the same time. I want to do this without using a for loop.

Just to get a clear idea here is the structure:

```
MainFolder
-abc.bat
 Subfolder1
 -a.bat
 Subfolder2
 -b.bat
 Subfolder3
 -c.bat
```

The batch file in Mainfolder (abc.bat) should be able to execute the 3 batch files in subfolders at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following command in `abc.bat` and let me know if this is what you want:

```
set CALL_PATH=%~dp0

start call %CALL_PATH%\Subfolder1\a.bat
start call %CALL_PATH%\Subfolder2\b.bat
start call %CALL_PATH%\Subfolder3\c.bat
```

After reading your comment, I think your problem is to run in the same screen while using `start`. For this you can use the `/I` flag

```
I           The new environment will be the original environment passed
            to the cmd.exe and not the current environment.
```

like so:

```
set CALL_PATH=%~dp0

start /I call %CALL_PATH%\Subfolder1\a.bat
start /I call %CALL_PATH%\Subfolder2\b.bat
start /I call %CALL_PATH%\Subfolder3\c.bat
```

If this does not help, please read the help for the start command using:

```
start /?
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer code frenzy. I want to run this abc.bat from a software called Hyperstudy ... so use of Start command in batch file does ot run the batch file from Hyperstudy. Is there any other way to run them without using the Start ?...